# How to define the following sets, given the provided formulas?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I have this problem: Define the following sets:
$$a) A=\left\{x\in \mathbb{Z} \mid \frac{6x}{2x+1} \in \mathbb{Z}\right\},$$

$$a) B \cap \mathbb{N}, \text{where } B = \left\{ \frac{105}{2}, \frac{106}{3}, \frac{107}{4}, \cdots, \frac{n+104}{n+1}, \cdots \right\}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I don't really understand what "define" means in this context, they, especially the first one seem well defined. If I write the second one as $B=\left\{x=\frac{n + 104}{n + 1} \in \mathbb{N} | n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$, it's pretty much the same thing. Maybe "defining" means listing all the elements, if there's a finite number of them, but I'm not sure, and that would require a proof. How would you interpret it?

Edit: People have suggested that both of these sets have a finite number of elements, so i'm looking for a thought process to list the elements of these sets respectively.

Comment: Yes, they are defined as they are. Doesn't the problem have a second part asking to do something more substantial with these sets?

Comment: The word "define" does strike me as strange in this context.  But it is true that both of those sets are finite, so your "list" interpretation may be what's intended.

Comment: Hmm.  The first is well defined but it isn't "well described"  without actively thinking about it, I don't know if it has any elements, finite number of elements, what elements are or are not in it.  So, I'm guessing, "dfining" it means providing a clearer definition.  But you are right.  It is currently "defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.  Both sets are defined.  I interpret the question to be redefine the sets so that their description is clearer.  Which, admittedly in theory, is subjective.

If $\frac {6x}{2x + 1} = k \in \mathbb Z; x  \in \mathbb Z$ then either $x = 0$ or $6 = k*(2 + 1/x)$ so $2 + 1/x \in \mathbb  Z$ so $x = \pm 1; k = 2, 6$.  So A = {0, 1, -1}.  (It'd be hard to argue that that isn't a clearer definition.)

I'll point out that in your post $ B\ne\left\{x=\frac{n + 104}{n + 1} \in \mathbb{N} | n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ but $C = B \cap \mathbb N =\left\{x=\frac{n + 104}{n + 1} \in \mathbb{N} | n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$.

$\frac {n + 104}{n + 1} = 1 + \frac {103} {n+1}$.  As 103 is prime, n =0 or n= 102.  Well, it depends on whether you define 0 to be a natural number but C = {104, 2} if 0 is natural, or {2} if 0 is not.

Comment: Perhaps "solve" for the sets make more sense.  Except I've never heard anyone say that before in my life.